# joomla article redirects to homepage

Tags: joomla3.0

I have installed a joomla template into my latest joomla cms. I created a article. And I linked this article to one of the submenu item. After saving wheni  check in the frontend, on clicking the sub menu the article url shows up but the page is redirected to homepage only. I have tried setting Search Engine Friendly URLs
to NO also Use URL Rewriting to NO. But still same issue. Also cleared cache. The issue is same in localhost host as well as on the server. If i try with any default template it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to share the site url?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i installed a new template and customized it and it works as desired. Thanks anyways. :)